# Assignment of integer variable address to class pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Child {
public:
    int b;
    void gotoSchool() {
        cout << "going to school";
    }
};

int main( )
{
    int a; 
    Child *p2 = (Child *) &a;  // #2
    p2->gotoSchool();

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is

```
going to school
```

but how is this working? How can an integer be typecasted to a user-defined class? Explain to me the concept behind this scenario, please.

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Don't use such code.

Comment: But why do c++ support these kind of conversion?Does it have any use in any other situation?

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't work? And if you think it shouldn't, why did you cast?

Comment: `Child *p2 = (Child *) &a;` You're using C-style cast on pointers, which means you say that from now on that variable should be treated as `Child*`, and if anything wrong happens it's your fault, you should use C++ static/dynamic casts instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing there is **just casting an address** and not an integer. For your computer an integer is a serie of bytes (4 bytes in a 32bits processor), let's put it a value of 8. This integer has an **address** (4 bytes in a 32bits processor too), let's say that the value of that address is 1.

In your code **you are casting the address of a**. So, pointer p2 has its address. A pointer is an address by definition. The arguments that your class "Child" will take in the casting are the byte values after "a" until it fills its data. *In this case, the data is a single int, so the value of "a" and the value of Child "b" is going to be the same one.* A pointer as it is just a memory address can be whatever type (consider a class a type you want). **The type only tells to the pointer what is the size of the data, and how to interpret it.** Now you have been unlucky and the type fits perfectly with the integer. But usually the behaviour of such casting is unespected.
I have modified your code in order to ilustrate what is happening, I think you will see it much more clear after executing it

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class Child {


public:
  float b;
  Child(){ b = -0.5;};
  void gotoSchool(){
  cout<<"going to school" << endl;}
  void changeValue(){ b = -0.5;};
  void displayB()
  {
     cout << "the value of b is " << b << endl;
  };
};

class OriginalChild {
public:
   int b;
   void gotoSchool(){
   cout<<"going to school";}
};

int main( )
{
  int a = 8;
  Child *p2 = (Child *) &a;  // #2
  OriginalChild *p3 = (OriginalChild *) &a;
  p2->gotoSchool();

  cout << a << endl;
  p2->displayB();
  cout << p3->b << endl;

  p2->changeValue();
  cout << a << endl;
  return 0;
}
```